# How to automatically feed in lines to a .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, io

I have an application whose entry point is like

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    int T = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int t = 0; t < T; ++t)
    {
        int[] line = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), Int32.Parse);
        int N = line[0], M = line[1];
        char[,] matrix = new char[M, N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            char[] row = Console.ReadLine().Where(c => c != ' ').ToArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
                matrix[j, i] = row[j];
        }
        int K = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var ff = new ForbiddenForest(matrix);
        Console.WriteLine(K == ff.OptimalMoveNumbers ? "Impressed" : "Oops!");
    }
}
```

and I have test input like

```
3
2 3
*.M
.X.
1
4 11
.X.X......X
.X*.X.XXX.X
.XX.X.XM...
......XXXX.
3
4 11
.X.X......X
.X*.X.XXX.X
.XX.X.XM...
......XXXX.
4
```

which I need to debug and which I don't want to manually type in to the console line-by-line. What would be the easiest way to feed this in to the program? Is there a way of writing batch file that would run `ThisProgram.exe` and feed it my test input?

Comment: You could make a text file of your test input... then read it into a string array, then loop thru the array and for each string in the array... process the string in your program.

Comment: If the application expects input until certain condition, you may also check [Send commands to a cmd window through a .bat file](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7078)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use Visual Studio as your development IDE:

You can feed input to your application for Debug purposes by putting these input in Project Properties > Debug > Command line arguments.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through a file with the for-loop in batch:

```
for /f "delims=" %%g in (yourInputFile.txt) do (
    ThisProgram.exe %%g
)
```

Also make sure, yourInputFile.txt is placed in the same directory as the batchfile and ThisProgram.exe . If they are not in the same directory you will have to change the directory using `cd path\to\files`